# $(window).load(function() is not getting executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this is my html code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Udxyb/406/

```
<div id="polls" style=" border: 1px solid #ccc;">


<table id="main_table" style="width: 1002px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">

    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 1</td>
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 2 </td>
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 3 </td>
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 4 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="section">
        <tr>
            <td>item 111</td>
            <td>item 112</td>
            <td>item 113</td>
            <td>item 114</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 121</td>
            <td>item 122</td>
            <td>item 123</td>
            <td>item 124</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 131</td>
            <td>item 132</td>
            <td>item 133</td>
            <td>item 134</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
           <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 1 </td>
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 2 </td>
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 3 </td>
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 4 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="section">
        <tr>
            <td>item 211</td>
            <td>item 212</td>
            <td>item 213</td>
            <td>item 214</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 221</td>
            <td>item 222</td>
            <td>item 223</td>
            <td>item 224</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 231</td>
            <td>item 232</td>
            <td>item 233</td>
            <td>item 234</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 1 </td>
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 2 </td>
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 3 </td>
            <td  colspan="" class="flip"> Section 4 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="section">
        <tr>
            <td>item 311</td>
            <td>item 312</td>
            <td>item 313</td>
            <td>item 314</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 321</td>
            <td>item 322</td>
            <td>item 323</td>
            <td>item 324</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item 331</td>
            <td>item 332</td>
            <td>item 333</td>
            <td>item 334</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


</div>
```

jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('.flip').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('tbody')
        .next('.section')
        .toggle('fast');
});
});

</script>
```

But when am getting the same code from java class using ajax and jdbc then am not able to get the jquery effect.what is the wrong  am doing here???

Comment: Your fiddle works. Have you included jquery.js in your page?

Comment: check browser console for any errors

Comment: Can you explain `But when am getting the same code from java class using ajax and jdbc`?

Comment: @archer i am getting the above html code from java class using ajax.then am getting all things printed but am not getting the toggle effect .

Comment: Curious, why are you using jQuery 1.5 in the fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using ajax to load the page contents, you're trying to attach event handlers to elements that do not exist on the page at the time.  Use this instead...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("document").on("click", ".flip", function() {
        $(this)
            .closest('tbody')
            .next('.section')
            .toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

`jQuery(function($) { })` is just another way of handling the document ready event.  You can swap it for `$(window).load()` if you have a reason for using that.

Also, swap `$("document")` for a selector for the container element.  In your code you have a div with class `.content`, so I'd suggest using that, but I'm not sure if that where you load the content or if that is part of the content.  You need to specify a parent/grandparent etc. element that is on the page at the time.

Comment: this is not working for me at all but thanks a lot!!

Comment: Can you post the code where you use ajax to load the contents.

Comment: there is nothing to post..actually if i run simple jsp page then every thing is working fine but when i am changing the of a div using ajax call then the tables are getting printed but toggle effect is not working...

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine for you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("DOM is ready");
});
```

As a shortcut, you can use

```
$(function() {
  alert("DOM is ready");
});
```

Make sure jQuery is included on your page before the above code is run (e.g.,)

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    alert("DOM is ready");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not true. `$(window).load(fn)` can be used to fire events after all the content of the page has been loaded.

Comment: That's fine, but I see nothing in his code that suggests he would need anything other than the tried-and-proven `$(fn);`

Comment: Fair enough, but changing the page hook event will have no effect as his code is currently working. Check the jsfiddle

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so what should i use??if it is wrong??

Comment: You should use `$(document).ready()` as it fires as soon as the DOM is up. `$(window).load(fn)` fires later, which means that a process which could have been done whilst your page is loading will be done after the page has loaded. However, this does not appear to be a cause of any issue you might have

Comment: This is all academic though.  His problem is that he loads the above html via an ajax call.  Either event delegation or binding the event handlers after load is what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try with document ready
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.flip').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('tbody')
        .next('.section')
        .toggle('fast');
});
});

</script>
```

If your html is loaded after an AJAX request, try with $(document).on
https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onFlipClick(event){
    $(this)
        .closest('tbody')
        .next('.section')
        .toggle('fast');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.flip', onFlipClick);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, please put this code after setting value through AJAX

```
$(".flip").on("click", function() {
        $(this)
            .closest('tbody')
            .next('.section')
            .toggle('fast');
    });
```